# How to know the type of a variable in Objective C on Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For example if I have a function sort() like so:

```
+ (void) sort: (id) a {
 if(typeof(a) == 'NSArray')
  { ... }
}
```

So is there anything in Objective C for Iphone which can go in place of typeof() so that I can detect beforehand what kind of variable am I dealing with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[a isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
```

Springs to mind.

I do want to point out though that in your case it makes more sense to simply type the method argument, rather than taking id and checking it's type, i.e.

```
+ (void)sort:(NSArray *)a
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I intend to pass it objects of various kinds, eg, NSArray, NSMutableArray, NSDictionary, NSMutableDictionary and so on and do operations based on the type.

Comment: That makes sense, but be warned it's often a symptom of a weak design.

Answer (score 1):

The [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html) Protocol has comparison methods that you will be interested in.